# Semantic UI React full page grid, how to hide overflowing column content?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a [full-page grid](https://j76k3jr0v.codesandbox.io/) that aligns it's height based on browser height with constant menu bar and footer height.

I am trying to limit the amount of content shown in some grid columns, so that even if the content is longer than the container it either shows y-scrollbar or is hidden.

Desired: Full page grid stays as it is, does not re-adjust the height based on the child element's height.

Please see the sandbox:

- Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j76k3jr0v

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [CSS overflow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/) feature to control how a container deals with content overflows.

In the case where one wants to use a scrollbar along the y-axis to allow for the scrolling through content beyond the bounds of a container, you can define the `overflow-y`  property as demonstrated in the following snippet:

```css
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Here is where I get a bit fuzzy on my understanding of CSS3 and Semantic UI. Using a `Grid.Column` with the `stretched` property set results to the `flex-flow` property being set on the element. This property maintains a relationship in the dimensions of its holder's children. I have tried playing around with your code and when used in tandem with the setting of the height of the children to an absolute value, i.e. expressed in units of `vh` or `px`, the design seems to yield results close to whatever you specified.

As a disclaimer, you should know that I chose the value for the height rather arbitrarily and it still worked, but I won't guarantee that this works on a wide range of window form-factors or across multiple browsers.

Here is a diff of FieldGrid.js based on your example files which is the only file that was modified to obtain the wanted results:

```
44c44
<                   <Segment>
---
>                   <Segment style={{ height: '1px', overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
55c55
<                   <Segment>
---
>                   <Segment style={{ height: '1px', overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
```

Based on your input, I have created another [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x29l0nv70o)) that you can play around with. Note how a height of 1px is obviously nonsensical but is still seems to work and also note that the `overflow-y` property has been specified for each element that needs the scrollbar.